# How to implement a generic react native backdrop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a generic component that should detect required component View outside click (hide the View/dropdown, etc. when pressed outside).  Basically it's for the Autocomplete Search Dropdown but I guess such functionality could be used in the future for other things.

- The content should be dynamic and could be passed from any level of the app because such functionality is a common UX thing.
- It shouldn't be modal that always render content at the screen center because a dropdown should be opened below its trigger, etc. So it should respect the initial component position. (In think to use onLayout/measure API of the initial position when passing the content into the Backdrop)

I researched a lot of resources and found that the one possible way is:

1. Create a TouchableWithoutFeedback layer (Backdrop) at the top level of the app.
2. make it fullscreen with/height
3. When dropdown is shown: render the Backdrop and onPress on it - close the dropdown & backdrop.

The main question is: **How to pass a generic content into this Layer and save its relationship with the parent/props, re-render when needed, etc.?**  
Please, keep in mind, that the component which should pass content for this layer could be deep inside the app.

I guess it could be done via Context API, etc. but I'm not sure if it's the best possible way.

P.S. in the case of web it's a trivial task: create a fullscreen layer -> use a portal -> move content at the top level of the app -> render it at the required X\Y position and listen for the outside press.
I didn't expect that such functionality will be a problem in the case of RN.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using react-native-paper ?

Comment: Hi Waheed Akhtar. No, I'm using pure React Native.

Comment: I was also in a similar situation where I have to use a generic component and I used this one https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-portalize.